# The error was: re.error: global flags not at the start of the expression at position 1 while running the ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

Can someone please assist how to fix this issue, why i am getting this error while running the Ansible playbook

> 2023-03-31 11:47:39,902 p=57332 u=NI40153964 n=ansible | An exception occurred during task execution.
> To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: re.error: global flags not at the start of the expression at position 1
> 2023-03-31 11:47:39,903 p=57332

Python & Ansible versions:

- Python 3.11.2
- Ansible [core 2.14.3]

The YML file which I am using as

```yaml
    - name: rename log file to user specific
      delegate_to: localhost
      command: mv ~/.ansible/wmDeployment.log ~/.ansible/wmDeployment_{{_user}}.log
      register: logfile_rename_output
      run_once: true
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: set the fact for email
      set_fact:
        package_list: "{{hostvars['localhost']['package_list']}}"
        log_output: "{{log_data| regex_search('((?s)(?<=This task is to install package in target servers).*?(?=This task is to enable kafka consumers and send mail of playbook log))')}}"
        emailkey: code
        cacheable: true
```

Comment: For your next question, please consider adding a more complete output where users can see the name of the task that is failing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is saying you need to put the `(?s)` at the very beginning of the regex. Alternatively, try something like

```
    log_output: "{{log_data| regex_search('(?s:(?<=This task is to install package in target servers)(.*?)(?=This task is to enable kafka consumers and send mail of playbook log))"
```

In some more detail, `(?s)` says *"I want the `s` flag for everything here"* or, in other words, a global flag. Python requires this to go at the very beginning of the regex, presumably to avoid weird and hard-to-debug problems which could happen if you had `(?s)` embedded somewhere in the middle of a long and complex regex. In fact, you could even argue that it's more likely a programming mistake than a considered, conscious decision.

By contrast, `(?s:...)` says *"I want to apply the `s` flag to the following subexpression,"* up to just before the closing parenthesis; this is obviously local to just the parenthesized subexpression, and could not be expressed by any other means.

In this concrete example, `((?s)foo)` is invalid, but equivalent to either `(?s)(foo)` or `(?s:(foo))` (or, in practice, `((?s:foo))`; or, if you don't actually care about the capturing group, simply `(?s:foo)`).